# How can I remove a problem in the `problems` tab in vscode

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

I am working in python and have used `exec(f'from {file} import myArray')`.
vscode then thinks that myArray is not defined later in code.
Is there a way to simply hide this error?

Comment: Why woud you do `exec(f'from {file} import myArray')` in the first place? And it's not an error, I guess it's just a warning from some lint you use

Comment: It is because I need to get a list from a file determined by `sys.argv`

Comment: This is clearly XY problem. There are way better approaches to read some values e.g. configuration or whatever than this

Comment: Not to mention the risks when execute arbitrary code determined by user input

Comment: I would suggest to add a concrete example of input/output to give you some alternatives.

Comment: I think there is a method `__import__` to import a file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may just be a warning for **linting**, add the following to your `settings.json` file to try and fix the problem.

```json
"python.linting.pylintArgs": [
    "--disable=E1101",
    "--disable=W,C"
]
```

Among them, `E1101` is the error code, which can be modified according to your situation. `W, C` are error levels.

*refer to:*

**C:** convention. Violating coding style standards

**R:** badly written code

**W:** some python specific question

**E:** Most likely a bug in the code

**F:** Error preventing pylint from running further

Or disable **linting** directly (**CTRL + SHIFT + P -->Python: Enable/Disable Linting-->Disable**).