# Ignoring a specific undefined variable with pyright

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, salt-stack, pyright

When writing custom SaltStack modules/states using VScode and linting with pyright, I get the following error all over the place:

```
"__salt__" is not defined
```

It's not a killer, because I can put the following on the end of every line that references it:

```
# pyright: ignore[reportUndefinedVariable]
```

But what I would rather do is tell my project that `__salt__` is a known variable, and don't report on that variable.

Is this possible?

Comment: If this is a problem caused by linting, is there any chance this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72668834/how-can-i-remove-a-problem-in-the-problems-tab-in-vscode) will help you?

Comment: `defineConstant` perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually worked out the correct solution which works with python newer than 3.5 and all the variables I'm tripping over.

```
from typing import Any, TYPE_CHECKING

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    __salt__: Any = None
    __states__: Any = None
    __opts__: Any = None
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do so by declaring the variable in the `__builtins__.pyi` file. See [this](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/blob/main/docs/builtins.md).